# Häufig verwendete Begriffe oder Sätze beim Fußballspiel

Tags: word-choice, standard-german

Ich spiele regelmäßig Fußball in einer Fußballhalle in einer Mannschaft von meiner Firma, aber meistens kann ich mich während des Spiels nicht gut ausdrücken. Was sind die häufig verwendeten **Begriffe** oder **Sätze** bei einem Fußballspiel?

Comment: "Mehr Bier!" SCNR ;-)

Comment: Was kam bei einer Websuche heraus? Schon bei Wikipedia geguckt?  https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glossar_von_Fu%C3%9Fballbegriffen

Comment: @Robert Actually, I would like to learn and/or hear some everyday-German terms. It is not easy to find these terms on a search. It should be learnt directly from the natives

Comment: Ich fürchte, das ist ein bisschen zu open-ended. Kannst du ein bisschen konkreter werden?

Comment: Ach ist das aufregend!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Objekte

- Platz: *Feld, Rasen, Acker, Grün*
- Ball: *Pille, Nille, Kugel, Leder, das Runde*
- Tor: *Kasten, Kiste, das Eckige*

  - Querbalken: *Latte*
  - Längsbalken: *Pfosten*
  - Netz: __
- Trikot: *Hemd*
- Hose: __
- Stutzen: __
- Schienbeinschoner: __
- Schuhe: __
- Stollen: __
- Handschuhe: __
- Kapitänsbinde: __
- Pfeife: __

### Ereignisse, Spielzüge

- Strafstoß: *Elfmeter, Elfer /elva/*
- Freistoß: __
- Anstoß: __
- Abstoß: *Abschlag*
- Eckstoß: *Ecke*
- Einwurf: __
- Verwarnung: *Gelbe Karte*
- Platzverweis: *Rote Karte, Arschkarte*
- Platzverweis nach Verwarnung: *Gelb-Rote Karte*
- Halbzeit: *Hälfte*
- Halbzeitpause: *Halbzeit*
- Spielzeitende: *Abpfiff*

### Personen, Positionen

- Angriff: *Sturm, Stürmer*
- Mittelfeld: *Linksaußen, Rechtsaußen, Läufer* (veraltet)
- Abwehrspieler: *Verteidiger, Manndecker, Libero, Vorstopper*

  - *Viererkette*
  - *Mauer*
- Torwart: *Torhüter, Keeper*

  - fliegender Wechsel: *letzter Mann, Fliege*
- Auswechselspieler: __
- Mitspieler: __
- Gegenspieler: __
- Trainer: __
- Schiedsrichter: *Schiri, Pfeife*

  - Linienrichter: __

### Ball bewegen

- erfolgreich bekommen: *annehmen, stoppen*
- allgemein mit dem Fuß: *schießen, kicken, bolzen, knolzen*
- hoher Ball zum Mitspieler: *flanken / Flanke, vorlegen / Vorlage, auflegen*
- flacher Ball zum Mitspieler: *passen / Pass, abspielen / Abspiel, abgeben*
- hoher Ball: *lupfen / Lupfer*
- mit dem Kopf: *köpfen / Kopfball*
- mit dem Ball laufen: *dribbeln*
- Zweikampf verlieren: *Ball verlieren, verdaddeln, vertändeln*
- Zweikampf gewinnen: *ausspielen, austricksen, austanzen, stehenlassen*
- Tor erzielen: *reinmachen, reinhauen*
- aufs Tor schießen: __
- am Tor vorbeischießen: *danebenhauen*
- aus der Distanz schießen: __

  - Foul begehen: *foulen*
  - Foul vortäuschen: *Schwalbe, schauspielern, markieren*

### Floskeln

- *den Kasten sauber halten*
- *ich bin/steh’ frei*
- *mach es*
- *schieß doch!*
- *spiel ab!*
- …

Comment: Na, der Libero ist aber aus der Mode. Wieso nicht Doppel-Sechs und falsche Neun...

Comment: Kein "Toor, toor, toor, I werd narrisch!" Oder ist das schon zu lange her? ;)

Comment: Vielen dank. Das war exakt was ich wollte.

Comment: @AdInfinitum Das war nur ein kurzes Brainstorming und ist alles andere als umfassend, besonders bei den Floskeln, und enthält praktisch keine Erklärungen – daher Community Wiki (und nur weil gerade EM ist).

Answer (score 1):

Beispiele:

- Hau das Ding rein!
- Spiel!
- Schneller!
- Lang!
- Leo! (= Laß den Ball durch!)
- Abschluß!
- Nimm ihn!

Comment: Könntest du bitte ein bisschen erklären, was "Hau das Ding rein", "Lang", "Abschluß" in diesem Kontext bedeuten?

Comment: @AdInfinitum "Hau das Ding rein" -> Schieß ihn rein ### "Lang" -> Langer Pass (in die Spitze) ### "Abschluss" -> Schieß aufs Tor